# Double variable substitution in bash

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

Program snippet:

```
BASH_MIN_REQ="2.05"
BINUTILS_MIN_REQ="2.12"
BISON_MIN_REQ="1.875"

BASH_CURR=$(bash --version | head -n1 | cut -d"(" -f1 | cut -d" " -f4)
BINUTILS_CURR=$(ld --version | head -n1 | cut -d" " -f7)
BISON_CURR=$(bison --version | head -n1 | cut -d" " -f4)

list=(BASH BINUTILS BISON)

for progs in ${list[@]}; do
    echo "$progs: ${${progs}_MIN_REQ}:${${progs}_CURR}"
done
```

Expected Output:

```
BASH: 2.05:4.3.11
BINUTILS: 2.12:2.24
BISON: 1.875:3.0.2
```

*Notice the variables initialized with the values. I want to substitute `${progs}_MIN_REQ` with `$BASH_MIN_REQ` and then again with the value it was initialized with that is 2.05. And do this inside the `for` loop so that will be easier for me to write the code as I'll have to write only 1 `echo` statement instead of 3.*

Actual output:

```
bad substitution
```

I know what I have written in `echo` is `wrong`. But is there a way to double substitute the variables. Otherwise I'll have to write lots of `echo` statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with indirection

```
for progs in ${list[@]}; do
     a="${progs}_MIN_REQ"
     b="${progs}_CURR"
     echo "$progs: ${!a}:${!b}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for progs in "${list[@]}"; do
  eval 'echo "$progs: ${'"${progs}"'_MIN_REQ}:${'"${progs}"'_CURR}"'
done
```

Comment: Your implementation has syntax errors at `${'`

Comment: @AbhimanyuSaharan, how so? `"${_list[@]}"` is `ksh`/`zsh`/`bash`/`yash` specific, but the `eval` line should be valid syntax in any Bourne-like shell.

Comment: `"$progs: ${'` has errors. Anyways meuh's answer worked for me.